# Why is this undefined?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to modify an element when it gets hovered, at some point, I need to get all elements with class name "image", my issue is that while allElements has a value inside of the main function (the first alert shows the value), allElements doesn't have a value anymore when called from the anonymous function (it is undefined).

What's wrong here ?

```
function register() {

    var i = 0
    var allElements = document.getElementsByClassName("image")
    alert(allElements) // Has a value
    while (i < allElements.length) {
        allElements[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            var description = null
            var j = 0
            alert(allElements[i]) // Undefined
            while (j < allElements[i].children.length) {
                var child = allElements[i].children[j]
                description = child
                if (child.id == "description") {
                    break
                }
                j++;
            }

            description.style = "display: block"

        });
        i++
    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: In the function in your event listener, you're referring to `allElements[i]`, which is no longer a valid reference. Replace it with `this`

Comment: try referencing it as `alert(this)` rather than the variable outside of the event listener

Comment: @ChrisForrence Do you mean `this.allElements[i]` ?

Comment: To expand on why it's undefined, when the `while` loop finishes, `i` has a value of `allElements.length` (since it increases by 1 on every tick of the loop, even before we exit). If there are 7 elements in `allElements`, then `i` will be 7, and `allElements[7]` does not exist. This is just for your conceptual understanding, follow the suggestions above for the actual fix.

Comment: @Amleonard But what is `this` referring to ?

Comment: @Amleonard How can `this` be equivalent to alert(allElements) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: I know it's semi-confusing because it happens behind the scenes, but the javascript engine binds the callback function to the *context* of the element that is listening to the event. The context is basically just what the value of `this` is inside the function. So when calling `allElements[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {`, the `addEventListener` function internally binds the callback function to have `this` equal to the element that is calling it.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise You should use `this` keyword to access element value in your addEventListener.  `this` it refers to an object; that is, the subject in context, or the subject of the executing code.

Comment: @Amleonard Oh I see, that's counterintuitive indeed... thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Just my 2c: what you're doing in js is much easier done with CSS, besides you seem to be looking for multiple child elements with an `id = "description"` attribute, you should use a CSS class instead. E.g.: `.image .description { display: none; } .image:hover .description { display: block }` - crossbrowser and works without js enabled

Answer (score 0):

By the time the event fires, `i` is equal to `elements.length`, so `elements[i]` is undefined - there is no such element as `elements[elements.length]`.

You'll want to read here: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) which explains the loop index variable issue in more detail.

For your specific issue, folks are recommending via comments to use `this`, because in the event handler the `this` object refers to the element that has been moused over, which allows you to avoid the loop index issue altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the event inside the function and access the element through the event.

```
allElements[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
  // code
  alert(e.target);
  // code
});
```